# How to sort a DataFrame by two columns, using a custom order?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame that I need to sort in a particular order in one column, and just ascending in another.
Both columns have repeated values.
It looks more or less like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
df[0] = pd.Series( [ 'a', 'aa', 'c' ] * 2 )
df[1] = pd.Series( [ 1, 2 ] * 3 )
df[2] = pd.Series( range(6) )
print( df )

    0  1  2
0   a  1  0
1  aa  2  1
2   c  1  2
3   a  2  3
4  aa  1  4
5   c  2  5
```

Now, say that I need to order by columns 0 and 1, but not alphabetically: Column 0 should first follow an order:

```
order = [ 'a', 'c', 'aa' ]
```

How do I do that?

I would like to have it sorted like this:

```
print( sorted_df )

    0  1  2
0   a  1  0
1   a  2  3
2   c  1  2
3   c  2  5
4  aa  1  4
5  aa  2  1
```

---

Using python 3.5.2, pandas 0.18.1

Comment: If you want it like that you could create an additional columns that holds the length of your strings in your `0`-column and then sort first by length of strings and then by the strings themselves.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use pandas' categorical Series for this purpose which supplies the functionality of an individual sort order:

```
 df[0] = pd.Categorical(df[0], order)
 print(df.sort_values([0, 1]))

    0   1   2
 0  a   1   0
 3  a   2   3
 2  c   1   2
 5  c   2   5
 4  aa  1   4
 1  aa  2   1
```

Comment: Hi, this one can help only if the 'order' given has unique elements. But how to custom sort if i want a column (say) from [1, 2, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4] order to [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2] ? Basically if want I want to sort the dataframe by cyclic list given.