# Sort pandas dataframe by predefined labels

Tags: pandas

i have a dataframe that has this column of interest level. Inside there are multiple levels : low, medium, high.

How do i sort the rows such that the rows are organized in low, medium, high instead.

Currently `df.sort` has only a feature of ascending and descending, which would not achieve what i want to achieve.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom sort orders on categorical variables, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42436225/how-to-sort-a-dataframe-by-two-columns-using-a-custom-order/42436754#42436754) in another SO question.